# Ordening search results per VAT rate

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named invoiceItems. It contains individual lines of an invoice. It has the following fields:

- invoiceItemId (primary key)
- invoiceId (primary key of the table Invoices)
- productId (primary key of the table products)
- Rate
- Quantity
- vatRate (0%, 6%, 12%, 21%)

I want to query the database and select all invoiceItems with a particular invoice number. Then I want to echo out the different vatRates that appear in that invoice, and the total VAT amount per vatRate.

For example, if the results were:

- invoiceItemId: 1, invoiceId: 17, productId: 23, Rate: 10 (€), Quantity: 10, vatRate: 6%
- invoiceItemId: 2, invoiceId: 17, productId: 7, Rate: 100 (€), Quantity: 1, vatRate: 21%
- invoiceItemId: 3, invoiceId: 17, productId: 8, Rate: 10 (€), Quantity: 5, vatRate: 12%

I would like to echo out:

INVOICE number 17

VAT 6% : € 6
VAT 12% : € 6
VAT 21% : € 21

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoiceItems WHERE invoiceId = ’17’”;
$query = $connect->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

I know I should loop through the results then, but I’m a bit stuck...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) operators build in in SQL.

```
    $sql = "SELECT vatRate, SUM(quantity * price * vatRate) as total FROM invoiceItems WHERE invoiceId = ’17’ GROUP BY vatRate”;
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()) { // Fetch for each vatrate
        // do what you want to do with the vats
        // use $result["vatRate"] and $result["total"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is what you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

you can then

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc($result)) {
      //print you stuff here
}
```

Check out the examples in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Does not handle duplicates

Comment: @inetphantom, yeah I didn't think about that, more giving the op a basic research starting point.